# Assembler Thumb Mode

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

im new in coding with Assembler and I have a question concerning the .thumb and .Syntax unified directive. I know there is a instruction set "Thumb", which contains 16-Bit commands, the Thumb2 set contains 16 and 32 Bit commands and so does the ARM instruction set. But I cannot understand what these 2 commands switch on/off.
Thanks

I tried to compile my code with different variations of .thumb and .syntax unified on and off but I can't recognize any difference.

Comment: The `.thumb` directive switches to the thumb instruction set, the `.arm` directive switches back.  For basic instructions, no difference is noticable on the assembler level.  UAL (what you select with `.syntax unified`) was designed to ensure this.

Comment: Did you look at the machine code in the disassembly?  Some instructions will be only 2 bytes in `.thumb` mode, like `adds r0, #1`

Comment: UAL made a hell of a mess is what it did, without the unified syntax you do have pre....unified, syntax which is more reliable as to getting the (all thumb targets) instruction encodings that you desire, with unified syntax it can be very painful.  Unified syntax is one of arms greatest failures.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, assembly language is specific to the assembler, and in this case settings.  ARM's assembly language for its various tools is not compatible with gnu and with clang and with others even if it is for the exact same arm core and instruction set as an example.  You cannot generically talk about any instruction sets assembly language as this is how assembly languages are.  .thumb and .syntax unified directives imply you are talking about gnu assembler, gcc assembler or clang (llvm) (three different assembly languages, with some overlap).

When ARM stood for Acorn RISC machines, they made actual chips, not IP.  And you had the arm1,arm2, and arm3 and some a version of one or 3 was 2a or something, you can look it up.  When it became an IP company and it stood for Advanced RISC Machines you had the arm7 product name and armv4t architecture name and thumb was born.  I the white and blue covered books in print the thumb instructions included (with typos) the equivalent ARM instruction.  At that time every thumb instruction had a direct arm equivalent (obviously not vice versa).

Thumb instructions are all 16 bit, the thumb2 extensions are formerly undefined thumb instructions that are decoded and then the additional 16 bits is decoded, so more proper to think of thumb or thumb+thumb2 as a variable length instruction set instead of 16 or 32.  Your choice as to how you view it and as to how you avoid confusion with the "full sized" arm instructions (non thumb).  Note originally bl and blx were two separate 16 bit instructions that did not have to follow each other, later with the cortex-ms the definition changed so they are a thumb2 if you will that is not a formerly undefined (all thumb variant) instruction.

So the armv4t thumb instructions, the original are the "all thumb variant" versions and some versions of the architectural reference manuals would use that term.  Latter manuals will call out the architecture names per instruction.

Likely some documentation slips but arm seems to have several different thumb instruction sets at least seven or more and I suspect it just means for example the differences between armv4t and armv5t which have to do with for example pop can be used to change modes where in armv4t only bx and blx.

The unified syntax has been confusing and bad since the beginning, but if you are just starting out on arm assembly language (not 64 bit) then you should probably suffer through it, as you will find most folks use it and gcc for example outputs unified syntax not pre-unified syntax.

The thumb documentation showed for example

```
ADD <Rd>, #<immed_8>
```

And that was the proper thumb syntax (well...assemblers choose their syntax, they do not have to follow some other language nor the document that is tied to some other assembly language).

The equivalent arm instruction is.

```
ADDS <Rd>, <Rd>, #<immed_8>
```

And the machine code for both was listed in the thumb portion of the documentation.

If you were to

```
adds r0,#1
```

or

```
add r0,r0,#1
```

in thumb mode you would get a syntax error (as one would hope).

Thumb2 extensions were a ton of years away, arm was still an also ran, although with this and the next few cores they became to dominate the processor world (your x86 box has more non-x86 processors than x86 processors in it, many arms and some number of 8051s and/or z80s, the x86 is an also-ran).  So UAL was born well before thumb2.

From our perspective there are basically three at least up to the early armv-8m, but it may change from there if not already.

The all thumb variant instructions, get the rev E version of the arm arm, the thick white cover book in print/paper (last of the print books) and the first pdf version of the arm arm.

The armv6-m which came with the cortex-m0.  This added a couple of dozen thumb2 extensions, formerly undefined instructions that are now two halfword instructions (32 bit if you must).

The armv7-m which started with the cortex-m3.  This added an additional 100-150 new thumb2 extensions over and above the armv6-m.

For some reason the non-UAL thumb instruction set in gas (gnu assembler) still exists and works great, I have code that is decades old.

The (flawed) concept was that you could write assembly language code using a unified syntax between arm of the day and thumb of the day.  Since there were tons of arm instructions that had no equivalent in thumb this made no sense, the only thing that kinda made sense is if you limited yourself to thumb instructions and then depending on the mode it would make the thumb instruction or the arm equivalent.  You could not write effective unified language code since you had to know which instruction set you were writing for and write code for that, which is what we were doing before the unified syntax, and after the unified syntax, so what was the point?  Two separate instruction sets, two separate assembly languages, just write code for the correct one.  Which is still what you have to do today.

A side effect was you could now

```
add r0,r0,#1
```

In non UAL syntax for gas.  Since it was functionally the same you get the same instruction.

```
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,r0,#1
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,#1
add r0,r0,#1
```

giving

```
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   8:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   c:   3001        adds    r0, #1
```

Note that as documented by arm (gas folks tend to not always follow the ip/chip vendors documented assembly language but in this case...) add r0,#1 and interestingly the disassembler person showed it as adds r0,#1.

Those are examples of the non-UAL that predated UAL.

So then we add ual.

```
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,r0,#1
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,#1
add r0,r0,#1
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   8:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   c:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   e:   eb01 0002   add.w   r0, r1, r2
  12:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
```

Now add r0,r1,r2 is a valid thumb2 instruction that is part of the many armv7-m thumb2 extensions.  And that is the encoding even though it looks kinda like the arm encoding.  That is not the arm documented syntax though, the arm documented syntax for that thumb2 instruction is add.w

Naturally if you are writing for a non-cortex-m before the armv6 period where this instruction was added.  You are now in trouble.  An instruction that will not work on your processor.  I am using an apt-gotten tool and could probably figure out the default processor since I did not specify one.  Which is a good idea:

```
.cpu cortex-m0
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,r0,#1
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
add r0,#1
add r0,r0,#1
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
```

and we get

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:3: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `add r0,r1,r2'
so.s:4: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `add r0,r0,#1'
so.s:10: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `add r0,r1,r2'
```

There are no arm instructions for that core so

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
```

gives

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:6: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `add r0,r1,r2'
```

Now the same tool saw it as a thumb instruction.  This is not the usual but an example of different, incompatible assembly languages, even within the same tool.  Most of the differences between assembly languages for the same targets are the directives and other subtle things, labels, comments, etc... Folks that port to gnu assembler seem like they want to intentionally make gnu assembler incompatible with the vendors own tools or documentation assembly language, the msr mrs instructions were quite painful for a while there.

So let's try

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
```

and it is happy with that

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   2:   eb01 0002   add.w   r0, r1, r2
   6:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
```

But let's be more correct.

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add.w r0,r1,r2
adds.w r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   2:   eb01 0002   add.w   r0, r1, r2
   6:   eb11 0002   adds.w  r0, r1, r2
   a:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
```

And that is all good.

As noted in comments above .thumb tells the parser the following instructions are thumb mode instructions.  .arm tells the parser the following instructions are arm mode instructions.

```
.cpu cortex-m3
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add.w r0,r1,r2
adds.w r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:3: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `add r0,r1,r2'
so.s:5: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `add.w r0,r1,r2'
so.s:6: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `adds.w r0,r1,r2'
so.s:7: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `adds r0,r1,r2'
```

The gnu assembler parser starts off in .arm mode.  So you do not have to specify it it is implied.

You can go back and forth as answered in a comment above.

```
add r0,r1,r2
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.arm
add r0,r1,r2

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   6:   0000        .short  0x0000
   8:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
```

(padding was needed to align the arm instruction, naturally this is completely broken code that cannot execute, it is just demonstrating the directives).

```
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.arm
add r0,r1,r2
```

.syntax unified indicates the code that follows (in either mode) is now using the UAL assembly language vs the non UAL assembly languages.

```
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax divided
add r0,r1,r2
```

gives

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   2:   eb01 0002   add.w   r0, r1, r2
   6:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
```

gnu assembler starts off in .syntax divided as we have seen already thus far.  so you start in .arm .syntax divided by default if you want to change either of those you have to use directives, and then until you use another directive to change the mode or syntax it remains that through the file.

Clearly (demonstrated above) if you want to do both .thumb and .syntax unified you can do those in either order as a pair for the rest of the file to use that language, gnu assembler thumb unified syntax.

The add instructions turned out to work first time, but there are other thumb instructions that it is quite painful to get them to not use the thumb2 version the tool will stick in the larger version instead.

In this case it works cleanly.

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
adds.w r0,r1,r2
adds.n r0,r1,r2



.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
adds.w r0,r1,r2
adds.n r0,r1,r2
```

a little confusion in the messages

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `add r0,r1,r2'
so.s:7: Error: selected processor does not support `adds.w r0,r1,r2' in Thumb-2 mode

.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.syntax unified
add.w r0,r1,r2
adds r0,r1,r2
adds.w r0,r1,r2
adds.n r0,r1,r2
```

better message now

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: selected processor does not support `add.w r0,r1,r2' in Thumb-2 mode
so.s:7: Error: selected processor does not support `adds.w r0,r1,r2' in Thumb-2 mode
```

If you are using arm assembly language in particular (risc-v is another one) you really really need to disassemble and examine often.  Even when compiling to make sure it is generating code that will run.  That also implies you know what core you have and what code will and will not run.

If you are just starting with arm assembly language with gnu assembler, first off use gnu assembler (arm-whatever-as) not gcc.  Learn real assembly language not inlined C assembly language which is yet another language.  Then learn to translate if you can absolutely justify using inline in the first place (rare).  Stick with the unified syntax, just put .syntax unified right up front get the tool in that mode from the start arm or thumb.  Understand that gnu assembler is not arms assembler, even if at times an arm employee may have worked on it, it is a separate assembly language.   It "tends" to follow the arm documentation as far as syntax goes and this far down the road it is much better at that than the early days.  Specifically I mean for the instruction syntax, not the other parts of the language.  Assume the arm documentation is unified syntax.  Always get the ARM Technical Reference Manual (ARM TRM) for the core you are using (and version!)  Always get the ARM Architectural Reference Manual for the core you are using (ARM ARM)(full sized armv6 does not exist have to split between the armv5t and the armv7a, and ignore a whole ton of the armv7a document).  ARMs programmers reference manuals are not good.  They have implications and incorrect statements that lead the non-gurus (and even arm gurus) into failure.  There are extremely rare nuggets if info in there that are of any use that are not properly documented in the product and architecture documents.  You may also wish to get the amba/axi documents for your core or -ish for your core, they help with exclusive access sometimes and the different buses that you find in some cores.  Generally the bus docs are advanced and for folks that have access to a core (work on a chip that has an arm core in it).

A couple of other directives for gnu assembler you need to know whether you are doing multi-language on a "full sized" arm or if you are working on a thumb only cortex-m.

In gnu assembler labels end with a colon : and there are some rules for what you can use for labels.  A label is an address that the tools compute for you, so you do not have to.  With gnu assembler the labels default as non-function labels.  If you stay in the same mode you are a bit safer, but if you are making mixed mode code, you need to use another set of directives to tell the tools that some labels are functions and some are non-function addresses (data or same mode branch destinations).

```
.syntax unified
.arm
here:
    bl one
    bl two
    b .
one:
    bx lr
three:
    bx lr
.thumb
.align
two:    
    bl three
    bx lr
```

gives (linked)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <here>:
    8000:   eb000001    bl  800c <one>
    8004:   eb000002    bl  8014 <two>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <here+0x8>

0000800c <one>:
    800c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008010 <three>:
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008014 <two>:
    8014:   f7ff fffc   bl  8010 <three>
    8018:   4770        bx  lr
```

Which is all kinds of broken.  You cannot bl from arm to thumb.  And the tools gave no warnings nor errors.

```
.syntax unified
.arm
here:
    bl one
    bl two
    b .
one:
    bx lr
three:
    bx lr
.thumb
.align
.thumb_func
two:    
    bl three
    bx lr
```

Now I do not expect this in general from tools but the gnu tools (I think after some major version) do this for you:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <here>:
    8000:   eb000001    bl  800c <one>
    8004:   eb000005    bl  8020 <__two_from_arm>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <here+0x8>

0000800c <one>:
    800c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008010 <three>:
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008014 <two>:
    8014:   f7ff fffc   bl  8010 <three>
    8018:   4770        bx  lr
    801a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    801c:   0000        movs    r0, r0
    ...

00008020 <__two_from_arm>:
    8020:   e59fc000    ldr ip, [pc]    ; 8028 <__two_from_arm+0x8>
    8024:   e12fff1c    bx  ip
    8028:   00008015    .word   0x00008015
    802c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

so that fixed it in one direction but not the other. From arm to thumb.
.thumb_func says the next label is a function (yes there is a lot of extra syntax you can use around the higher level language concepts of functions or procedures, etc.  at a minimum it boils down to this).  So it is positional, you do not have to put it on the line immediately before, you can have other stuff in there that is not a label.

There is no .arm_func, instead

```
.syntax unified
.arm
.type here,%function
.type one,%function
.type three,%function
here:
    bl one
    bl two
    b .
one:
    bx lr
three:
    bx lr
.thumb
.align
.thumb_func
two:    
    bl three
    bx lr
```

.type ... %function is used.  And since the label name is in the directive you do not have to put it in front of the label.

.type works for thumb as well, and does not even have to be within the .thumb area

```
.syntax unified
.arm
.type here,%function
.type one,%function
.type three,%function
.type two,%function
here:
    bl one
    bl two
    b .
one:
    bx lr
three:
    bx lr
.thumb
.align
two:    
    bl three
    bx lr
```

and although this code is not really usable, at least it does not crash from switching instruction sets without properly switching modes.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <here>:
    8000:   eb000001    bl  800c <one>
    8004:   eb000005    bl  8020 <__two_from_arm>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <here+0x8>

0000800c <one>:
    800c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008010 <three>:
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008014 <two>:
    8014:   f000 f80a   bl  802c <__three_from_thumb>
    8018:   4770        bx  lr
    801a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    801c:   0000        movs    r0, r0
    ...

00008020 <__two_from_arm>:
    8020:   e59fc000    ldr ip, [pc]    ; 8028 <__two_from_arm+0x8>
    8024:   e12fff1c    bx  ip
    8028:   00008015    .word   0x00008015

0000802c <__three_from_thumb>:
    802c:   4778        bx  pc
    802e:   e7fd        b.n 802c <__three_from_thumb>
    8030:   eafffff6    b   8010 <three>
    8034:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Oh, so gnu linker adds these trampolines (they use another name) to switch modes for you.  You have to link to see them.  I would assume that older versions of the tools and or other toolchains, which will have their own syntax for these declarations, might give a warning if you bl to a label in an area that is the wrong instruction set.

At least with current versions you will see gcc will generate both .type and .thumb_func for thumb function labels.

If you are working on a cortex-m for the most part you do not need to declare the labels as functions as there are no mode switches, but the vector table needs thumb function addresses (address of the function ORRed with one. If you think plus one you get in trouble).

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.syntax unified
.thumb
.word 0x20000800
.word reset

.align
reset:
    b .


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <reset-0x8>:
   0:   20000800    .word   0x20000800
   4:   00000008    .word   0x00000008

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <reset>
```

Now that is wrong that will not boot.  The vector table requires the lsbit be set per the documentation.

This hack does not work for some reason even though the docs imply it should.

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.syntax unified
.thumb
.word 0x20000800
.word reset|1

.align
reset:
    b .

so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:6: Error: invalid operands (.text and *ABS* sections) for `|'
```

so sometimes you see this dreadful hack

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.syntax unified
.thumb
.word 0x20000800
.word reset+1

.align
reset:
    b .

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <reset-0x8>:
   0:   20000800    .word   0x20000800
   4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <reset>
```

Just do it right

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.syntax unified
.thumb
.word 0x20000800
.word reset

.align
.thumb_func
reset:
    b .

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <reset-0x8>:
   0:   20000800    .word   0x20000800
   4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <reset>
```

(yes if you do both the tool actually saves you from yourself).

Note the specific gnu assembler or gcc binaries you are using are programs themselves that were built with some specs.  You can build them to default to armv4t or arm7a or whatever.  And if you do not indicate the core then it uses that default (you can build a gnu assembler that breaks the examples above from giving the same results as the one I used).

---

In short, as already answered in a comment above.

gnu assembler starts in arm mode with divided syntax.  Which means build the following instructions using the arm instruction set, using non unified syntax (until other directives say otherwise)

.thumb indicates the code that follows this directive is to be built using the thumb instruction set (until other directives...)

.syntax unified means the code that follows is to be parsed using this tools version of the unified syntax.

.arm indicates that the code that follows this directive is to be built using the arm instruction set

.syntax divided means the code that follows is to be parsed using this tools version of the specific syntax for each mode.

.syntax unified/divided apples to both .arm and .thumb directives that follow. You may wish to just put .syntax unified at the top of every file.

thumb more than arm "instruction sets" are a tricky business as somewhat indicated above.  But these directives combined with the target core/processor specified, define the supported arm and/or thumb instructions for that target. arm mode has added some new instructions over time but not like thumb full sized or cortex-m which saw a large number of additions.  Need to specify the right core or a lesser core that has a subset that is completely supported by the core you are using (armv4t or armv6-m/cortex-m0 for example).

You stated not being able to see the difference.

```
add r0,r1,r2
.thumb
add r0,r1,r2
.syntax unified
add r0,r1,r2

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
   6:   eb01 0002   add.w   r0, r1, r2
```

An arm, thumb, and thumb2 version of the same syntax, but one is not functionally the same as the other two.  You can definitely see the difference though.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to compile my code with different variations of .thumb and .syntax unified on and off but I can't recognize any difference.

There should be no difference; that is expected.  ARM assembler is somewhat unique in that the mnemonics can map to different binary values.

Consider an assembler 'library' for utility functions.  It can be written in 'unified' and then your `.thumb` caller can use that code.  The assembler options will determine that the 'unified' library should produce thumb binary output.  Hopefully you can see the value of that.

So `.thumb` says you will only produce the Thumb code.  The `.syntax unified` is writing assembler that can target **EITHER** binary.  Either legacy 32bit or the Thumb.  With later 'thumb2' sets, there is almost 100% op-code correspondence.  Initial 'thumb1' only allowed access to registers R0-R7 and had many limitations.  It would be difficult to write 'unified' code on these CPUs.

For modern Cortex-A CPUs, you can write assembler that works in either mode.  It could be useful if you need to support an ARMv4 CPU that does not understand Thumb.  For newer Cortex-A, thumb2 is a better binary encoding to use.  Better code density and performance.  This was not the case for ARMv5 (thumb1) cpus.  For ARMv6, it was somewhere in the middle with thumb being usually better.